# How to use a laptop as an external Wi-Fi adapter for another laptop?

Tags: networking, wireless, adapter

I'm trying to use a program which needs two Wifi adapter. But I have two laptop which have only single wifi adapter. I'm planning to use B laptop as second wifi adapter for A laptop so I can use the program with my A laptop and the program detect two wireless adapter.
Is it possible? I'm using BackTrack 5 which is based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Which programm you are trying to use?

In case you just need the second connection and not the adapter itself, you could use a socks proxy connection via ssh. See [Dynamic Port Forwarding - Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding).

Comment: No, it actually needs two wifi adapter. I want to use "WifiPhisher".

Comment: Ok, then I'm afraid I can't help. Sorry...